# jQuery Validator addMethod not updating UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Since the rule says 'emailAccountExists' needs to evaluate to true, if the email account exists, I am returning false.
When I log the responses out, and what I'm returning out - the logic is working correctly.
However, my UI is not updating. The system always thinks the email account exists. Even when the log statements say otherwise.

I have tried the 'remote' method as well...

I thought it was a timing problem, so I have set 'async' to false. Still no luck. I'm not sure what else to try.

**JavaScript:**

```
'rules': {
    'email': {
        'required': true,
        'email': true,
        'hasValidEmailAddress': true,
        'emailAccountExists': true
    }
....
}

$.validator.addMethod('emailAccountExists', function(value, element) {
    $.ajax({
        'url': '/my-url?email=' + value,
        'type': 'get',
        'dataType': 'text',
        'timeout': 50000,
        'async': false,
        'success': function(response) {
            console.log((response === '"true"') ? false : true);
            return (response === '"true"') ? false : true;
        },
        'error': function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('ERROR');
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}, messages.duplicateEmailAddress);
```

Using the 'remote' method:

```
'remote': {
    'type': 'get',
    'url': '/my-url?email=' +    ('#email').val()
}
```

It is always returning false.

Comment: Why not use the `remote` rule that's already part of this plugin?

Comment: I tried that as well. I apologize, I should have included that. I have updated my example.

Comment: If that's always returning `false`, then show the server-side function too.

Comment: You do not need to pass the value in through the URL query string.  The value is already part of the `$_GET` array.

Comment: Thank you Sparky! I updated to not include the value and i am getting the correct true/false now at least. This will get me rolling again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to pass the value of the field through the query string...

```
'remote': {
    'type': 'get',
    'url': '/my-url?email=' +    ('#email').val()
}
```

Simply use the `$_GET` array on the server-side code.  Also since `GET` is the default, this is all you'd need...

```
rules: {
    email: {
        // the other rules,
        remote: '/my-url'
    }
}
```

See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

You'll have to show your server-side code if you need more assistance.